# Need to use Group by in SQL on an Arithmetic column

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by

I want to use Group by in below query on a column MEDICINE_NAME but facing an error, anyone please help me how can I use it.

```
SELECT m.doc_date "Date of Purchase",
         t.cost_unit "Purchase On",
         t.price_unit "Sold On",
         t.price_unit - t.cost_unit "Margin",
         CONCAT (
            ROUND ( ( (t.price_unit - t.cost_unit) * 100 / (t.cost_unit + 1)),
                   2),
            '%')
            "Profit",
         med.medicine_name,
         med.manufacture,
         v.vendor_name
    FROM rrmaster m,
         rrtran t,
         medicine med,
         vendor v
   WHERE     m.doc_no = t.doc_no
         AND m.doc_type = t.doc_type
         AND m.storecode = t.storecode
         AND med.medicine_code = t.id_no
         AND m.doc_date LIKE '%17'
         AND m.source = v.code
GROUP BY med.medicine_name;
```

ERROR

> ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression
>   00979. 00000 -  "not a GROUP BY expression"
>   *Cause:
>   *Action:
>   Error at Line: 1 Column: 8

Regards
Soban

Comment: You are grouping by the medicine name, but the selecting many other columns, which are not aggregates.  That doesn't make much sense.  Pleased edit your question, add some sample data, and explain what you are trying to do here.

Comment: You typically GROUP BY the columns you select, except those who are arguments to set functions.

Comment: Tip of today: Switch to modern, explicit `JOIN` syntax! Easier to write (without errors), easier to read and maintain, and easier to convert to outer join if needed.

Comment: See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Boracle%5D+ORA-00979) for many answers

Comment: Hi @TimBiegeleisen, Thanks for your quick response, I am newbie in writting complex queries, I want to fatch a data on the basis of medicine_name so that the medicine of same name can be shown collectivly, can you please help me how can i do that?

Comment: Dear @jarlh, I am working on using joins, thanks for your words.

Comment: Please show an example of your desired results.

Answer (score 1):

Please try the below, when [aggregate functions](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions003.htm) are used, all non-aggregate columns must be included in the `GROUP BY` clause

```
SELECT doc_date "Date of Purchase",
       cost_unit "Purchase On",
       price_unit "Sold On",
       price_unit - cost_unit "Margin",
       profit,
       medicine_name,
       manufacture,
       vendor_name
  FROM (  SELECT m.doc_date,
                 t.cost_unit,
                 t.price_unit,
                 t.price_unit,
                 t.cost_unit,
                 CONCAT (
                    ROUND (
                       ( (t.price_unit - t.cost_unit) * 100 / (t.cost_unit + 1)),
                       2),
                    '%')
                    "Profit",
                 med.medicine_name,
                 med.manufacture,
                 v.vendor_name
            FROM rrmaster m,
                 rrtran t,
                 medicine med,
                 vendor v
           WHERE     m.doc_no = t.doc_no
                 AND m.doc_type = t.doc_type
                 AND m.storecode = t.storecode
                 AND med.medicine_code = t.id_no
                 AND m.doc_date LIKE '%17'
                 AND m.source = v.code
        GROUP BY m.doc_date,
                 t.cost_unit,
                 t.price_unit,
                 t.price_unit,
                 t.cost_unit,
                 med.medicine_name,
                 med.manufacture,
                 v.vendor_name)
```